# How to fix Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have values ​​in an array object called farms. In this case, we are using the farms.map function.
However, this warning occurred, and when I searched the documentation, it was telling me to write a unique value for key.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. in React native?
```

So I wrote v.placeId in the key in the TargetCon component, but the warning was not resolved. How do I fix it?

this is my code

```
    farms = [
    {
        placeId: 272,
        name: 'hamburger',
    },
    {
        placeId: 273,
        name: 'coffee',
    },
    ];

    const TargetFarm = () => {
    const {farms} = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post);

    return (
        <SeCotainer platform={tablet}>
        {farms.map(v => {
            return (
            <>
                <TargetCon key={v.placeId.toString()}>
                <TargetTxt platform={tablet}>{v.name}</TargetTxt>
                </TargetCon>
            </>
            );
        })}
        </SeCotainer>
    );
    };

    export default TargetFarm;
```

Comment: Replace your empty fragment (<></>) with <React.Fragment key={v.placeId.toString()}>...rest</React.Fragment>

Also good to remember, whatever key you use it needs to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the key attribute in root element within the loop

```
return (
        <React.Fragment  key={v.placeId.toString()}>
            <TargetCon>
                 <TargetTxt platform={tablet}>{v.name}</TargetTxt>
            </TargetCon>
        </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` inside map() Function

```
  return (
      <SeCotainer platform={tablet}>
      {farms.map((v, index) => {
          return (
          <React.Fragment key={`targetcon_${index}`}>
              <TargetCon key={v.placeId.toString()}>
              <TargetTxt platform={tablet}>{v.name}</TargetTxt>
              </TargetCon>
          </React.Fragment>
          );
      })}
      </SeCotainer>
  );
```

Comment: using index as a key should be used as a last resort. 
More about this: https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/

Answer (score -1):

In the above code, you have converted the value of the key into a string that wouldn't work

Refer to the below code I have made the changes:

```
    farms = [
{
    placeId: 272,
    name: 'hamburger',
},
{
    placeId: 273,
    name: 'coffee',
},
];

const TargetFarm = () => {
const {farms} = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post);

return (
    <SeCotainer platform={tablet}>
    {farms.map(v => {
        return (
        <>
            <React.Fragment key={`targetcon_${index}`}>
              <TargetCon key={v.placeId.toString()}>
                <TargetTxt platform={tablet}>{v.name}</TargetTxt>
              </TargetCon>
            </React.Fragment>
        </>
        );
    })}
    </SeCotainer>
);
};

export default TargetFarm;
```

Comment: you still have a empty fragment here with no key. the key should be on the top level, and im also pretty sure you'll get warnings  for providing a key that is not a string.